# Using same alias in two or more DIFFERENT correlated subqueries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

Say I have a Select list with some correlated subqueries, like:

```sql
OutputColumnAlias1 = (select min(somedate)
                      from Table1 t1
                      where t1.patientid=OuterTableAlias.patientid
                      and t1.labname='labname1')
OutputColumnAlias2 = (select min(somedate)
                      from Table1 t1
                      where t1.patientid=OuterTableAlias.patientid
                      and t1.labname='labname2')
```

Is it acceptable to repeat t1 in the second subquery, because it's "scope" will only be limited to the inside of that parenthetical?

Or am I unwittingly producing a bad result because, due to the first subquery, t1 will forever be defined by it's first referenced instance's WHERE clause, (etc) ?

Setting aside the badness of correlated subqueries for a moment, please advise?

Comment: The subqueries aren't in the same scope, so reusing the alias isn't a problem here

Comment: That was my original intuition, and I believe that somehow you are probably right as you're probably further along in this than I am, but when I made the aliases distinct it did solve the problem that I was seeing whereby whatever was the result value in the first subquery for a given patient would then be the same for all of the remaining subqueries for that patient...